# How do i set up a Fibre Channel HBA adapter as a network device?

Tags: networking

How do i use an HBA adapter as a network device? I want to connect one HBA adapter on one machine to the HBA adapter on another machine and use them like a traditional network device

My type of HBA adapter seems to be working. It appears as an Emulex LPe15000/LPe16000 device in “lspci”.

And i have all the fibre channel data listed in /sys/class like described in this redhat article https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_storage_devices/using-fibre-channel-devices_managing-storage-devices

But i would like to connect from one card to another as a simple network interface. So i can use scp, samba, etc. I want it to appear in “ip addr” command

This is the hardware product: IBM 00RY004 2-Port 16Gb Fibre Channel Host Bus Adapter Network Card. But it seems like the firmware on it is Emulex. And i have two of these cards, on two different machine, connected with a single fibre cable. I could also buy a central “router” or switch if something unknown needs to be between them but I dont know what that would be.

How do i use it as a simple network interface?

Comment: Are you sure doing so is supported in the first place? Search results are telling me Linux stopped supporting IPoFC some 10 years ago.

Comment: [This thread on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/103013/using-san-fiber-channel-network-for-tcp-ip-possible) might help you somewhat. It might also be that you find people more knowledgable over there. Be aware that Fibre channel "is designed to connect general purpose computers, mainframes and supercomputers to storage devices". So, doing networking over it is not a simple feat. In any case, it will be far from "a simple network interface", as you'd wish it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fibre Channel and Ethernet are two separate and incompatible technologies
created to solve different problems.
Plugging a Fibre Channel cable into an Ethernet fiber switch will just
not work.

Fibre Channel protocol was originally created to connect computers to
disk drives.
It was designed from the grounds up to be a "transport" protocol,
not a network protocol. It does not relate at all to the
[OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)
on which networking protocols are based.

Nevertheless, Ethernet and Fibre Channel can encapsulate data frames
one over the other.
For Fibre Channel frames to encapsulate Ethernet frames is called
[Ethernet over Fibre Channel](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2015/04/01/ethernet-over-fibre-channel/)
or "EoFC".

For compatibility with Ethernet/TCP/IP stacks, you need a CNH
(Converged Network HBA).

The [Converged network adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converged_network_adapter)
is defined as:

> A converged network adapter (CNA), also called a converged network interface controller (C-NIC), is a computer input/output device that combines the functionality of a host bus adapter (HBA) with a network interface controller (NIC). In other words, it "converges" access to, respectively, a storage area network and a general-purpose computer network.

So your HBA adapter is not the right hardware.
It only does one half of the job.

You got the same answer for your (closed) post on
[networkengineering.stackexchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77815/how-do-i-set-up-an-hba-adapter-as-a-netw):

> A Fibre Channel HBA *is* a network interface (for a Fibre Channel
> network/fabric), as well as a host adapter. However, it's *not an
> Ethernet interface* which seems to be your aim.
>
> Some few FC HBAs can optionally run Ethernet (and FCoE) but an
> LPe15000 doesn't seem to have that option.

You need to get Converged network adapters, not HBA adapters,
to establish Ethernet over Fibre Channel. The usefulness of this
hardware might not warrant the expense.

Comment: I always thought Ethernet was the name of plug design. And sometimes I still think that. Like for this product https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c03572669&docLocale=en_US, are simple transceivers like IBM 00RY190 compatible? Or do I need a transceiver with a female Ethernet port on it? I know Ethernet is the name of a protocol now, but it's also the name of a plug design, which is what makes this so confusing...

Comment: It looks like one is SR and the other is SW. And I'm not sure if the 16GB of the IBM can be downrun to 10GB. But there are 10GB SR transceivers for $7.70 on ebay so.... I will just get that.... And to answer my last comment, they use fibre channel cables, not ethernet cables.

Comment: This came up cause of a new answer and it looks a lot like the datacenteroverlords link is the only reference to EOFC and  apparently an april fools day joke? https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/post/ip-over-fibre-channel-hack suggests its doable with an amazing amount of hackery and self loathing... but its a different approach from your original link

Comment: @nickcarraway Ethernet has never been the name of a plug design.  You are probably referring to either [8P8C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C) (also often called RJ45) or [SFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Form-factor_Pluggable).  When Ethernet was first designed it used [AUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_Unit_Interface) and later [BNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_connector), so even from the beginning none of the connectors were ever called "Ethernet".

Answer (score 1):

ARGH STOP LINKING [THIS](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2015/04/01/ethernet-over-fibre-channel/) its was an April Fools joke and not actual documentation!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1122402)

Answer (score 1):

Update 05FEB2023:
Whilst for many FC cards (if not all), the previous answer is technically correct, there are exceptions to this. There are cards on the market that were/are sold to benefit customer environments that may currently use a converged storage topology (hence a CNA or Converged Network Adapter / C-NIC) but have plans to upgrade to FC based topology down the line. Take for example an environment where there is a preexisting NAS and the customer upgrades their servers, the customer can choose to use one of these dual-mode CNA's to use their existing storage setup for now, and then reuse this hardware in FC mode after upgrading the storage deployment in the future. The card does not run in FC mode at the same time as it is operating on a TCP/IP based network. However, it may support either FC 16Gb or 10GbE.

Take for example the QLogic QLE8362, which is a CNA, that can also run in FC mode. There also exist switches that can operate in both modes. The first that comes to mind are the Brocade VDX series switches (purchased by Extreme Networks), such as the VDX-6720 or 6740. These switches can operate in 10GbE based networking. They can accept native FC 16Gbs optics as well. And they can also operate in more hybrid topologies with FCoE.

The point is, it is technically incorrect that there aren't cards on the market that can function in both FC or TCP/IP modes. The best advice I would give to anyone wondering if this is possible is to check the datasheet for the card your using. I'm not aware of OEM cards from Dell or HPE that can do this. However the more 'niche' or 'dedicated' players in these spaces may often have strategic, flexible options for these scenarios and the market is flooded with this kind of hardware from the last 5-10 years these days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).